# Why is there a "reference free" option in DPO (Direct Preference Optimization)'s loss function?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, natural-language-processing, large-language-models, loss

There is a [reference_free](https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/d708ec272f292ded00a4d0f14b5bd214741b87f3/trl/trainer/dpo_trainer.py#L762) parameter in [trl](https://github.com/huggingface/trl)'s loss function implementation of DPO, while [the original DPO paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18290) does not mention the concept of "reference free".

In trl's implementation:

```
    pi_logratios = policy_chosen_logps - policy_rejected_logps
    if reference_free:
        ref_logratios = 0
    else:
        ref_logratios = reference_chosen_logps - reference_rejected_logps

    logits = pi_logratios - ref_logratios
```

When `reference_free` is `True`, the loss is calculated as cross entropy between `policy_chosen_logps` and `policy_rejected_logps`, while `reference_chosen_logps` and `reference_rejected_logps` are not in use.

What are the pros and cons of the "reference free" DPO?

Comment: Hi @Yang Bo and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! To receive an answer on this question, it might help to add a few more details. Thank you for posting, and we hope to see more of your questions on this site in the near future!

Comment: @DeepQZero Thank you for your warm welcome message. I just added the related code and my interpretation of the implementation.